# Python correct Deep Reverse function?

Tags: python

The function deepReverse should be returning a fully reversed list, with all lists in it also reversed, but it is only returning the last element of L (a list) reversed. I don't know how to fix this so that the recursion continues for the original list L.

Is doing:

```
deepReverse([1, [2, 3], 4, [5, 6]]) -> [6, 5]

deepReverse([1, [2, 3], 4, [5, 6]]) -> [6, 5]
```

Should do:

```
deepReverse([1, [2, 3], 4, [5, 6]]) -> [[6, 5], 4, [3, 2], 1]

deepReverse([1, [2, [3, 4], [5, [6, 7], 8]]]) -> [[[8, [7, 6], 5], [4, 3], 2], 1]
```

Current code:

```
def deepReverse(L):
    ''' Returns reversed list with all lists contained in it also reversed '''
    def deepReverse_helper(L, newlst):
        if L == []:
            return newlst
        if isinstance(L[-1], list):
            # element in L is a list
            return deepReverse_helper(L[-1], [])
        else:
            # element in L is not a list
            return deepReverse_helper(L[:-1], newlst + [L[-1]])
    return deepReverse_helper(L, [])
```

Comment: The problem is that the very first (well, second) thing you do is check to see if the last item of your input list is itself a list. If it is, you return the reverse of it. And that's it. You don't do anything with the rest of the list at all. You need to do something with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def deepReverse(L):
    def deepReverse_helper(L, newlst):
        if L == []:
            return newlst
        if isinstance(L[-1], list):
            # element in L is a list
            return deepReverse_helper(L[:-1], newlst + [deepReverse(L[-1])])
        else:
            # element in L is not a list
            return deepReverse_helper(L[:-1], newlst + [L[-1]])
    return deepReverse_helper(L, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why it is complicated than necessary, Can't you try a one-liner like this?

```
def deep_reverse(L):
    return [deep_reverse(l) if type(l) is list else l for l in reversed(L)]

>>> deep_reverse([1, [2, 3], 4, [5, 6]])
[[6, 5], 4, [3, 2], 1]
```

Comment: While this is very clean, it doesn't make for a great learning experience if the OP is new to Python. An explanation might help?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that you're recursing for two different purposes. First, you're recursing to reverse an inner list, if you find one. Secondly, you're recursing in place of iterating over your main list. You may need to do *both* in a single call to the helper function.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
def deep_reverse(L):
    def deep_reverse_helper(L, result):
        if not L:
            return result   # base case
        first, *rest = L
        if isinstance(first, list):
            first = deep_reverse_helper(first, [])   # first recursion (not always needed)
        result.append(first)
        return deep_reverse_helper(rest, result)   # second recursion
    return deep_reverse_helper(L, [])
```

I avoid making an extra unnecessary copy of the `result` list each run by using `append` instead of concatenating two lists. This code is still `O(N**2)` because the list unpacking (`first, *rest = L`) takes `O(N)` time. You could do the same thing with a slice, if you prefer, but it would have exactly the same performance.

Using iteration for the outer list (while still recursing to handle nested lists) would be much more natural in Python. [itsneo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46229956/1405065) shows a pretty good way to do that. Here's a less terse version, that might be easier to understand if you're new to Python:

```
def deep_reverse(L):
    result = []
    for value in reversed(L):
        if isinstance(value, list):
            value = deep_reverse(value)
        result.append(value)
    return result
```

Comment: Although this does answer the question and it does make sense to use "for", if I'm not allowed to use "for", how can this be done without the "for" statement?

Comment: The first code block shows a solution that is purely recursive (no loops other than the implicit one in the unpacking operation).